Looking for werewolf story where the woman and man turn out to be gods
I’m looking for a story about a girl who had purple eyes. She got them from her missing father who raped her mother and then rejected her because he wanted to become alpha. She has a mate but hides her scent from him so he doesn't recognize her but still likes her… In the end she turns out to be the Moon Goddess and her mate an ancient guy who was imprisoned by the Sun God.

Was this a novel? Online story? Webcomic? Manga?

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

The site forbids us to answer with the help of AI tools such as ChatGPT, etc. But I believe you're referring to The Moon Goddess and Her Mate by Priskila Wi.
